# Can cmake configuration run in parallel?

Tags: cmake

I know that the cmake build stage can be done in parallel, but the initial configuration stage takes too long for large packages. Can that be parallelized?

Comment: **Configuration stage** is about reading and interpreting of `CMakeLists.txt` file and all files it includes. This is essentially a sequential process and cannot be parallelized. There is following **generation stage**, which takes the inner representation of configuration data and creates Makefiles (or other files, for non-Make generators). But generation stage is lasting since "Configuring done" message till "Generating done", which is probably not so long in your case.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I was wondering why the "done" stage took so long. But yes, that's minor. My cmake script checks tons of compiler options, as wel as the presence of all sorts of external packages that it can configure with. All that is conceptually as parallel as can be. Such a shame that apparently it can't be in actuality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No**, the configuration stage cannot be parallelized.

Nonetheless, here are some things you could do:

### Profile the Configuration Phase

CMake has [--profiling-output/--profiling-format](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#cmdoption-cmake-profiling-output) options, which emits a file that can be opened e.g. in Chromium-based browsers using `about:tracing`. This visualizes all command that were processes by CMake, how long they took, how they are nested, etc. This information can be used to find bottlenecks in your configuration phase and possibly optimize them to run faster. This is especially useful if you have a lot of custom functions/macros in your CMake files. Example:

```bash
$ cmake -G Ninja --profiling-output ./profile.json --profiling-format google-trace ..
```

[image: about:tracing]

> Note that the profiling itself poses some additional work on CMake. Therefore, while profiling the CMake run will take longer as usual.

### Generate Less Configurations

Running CMake actually does two things: configure and generate. Configure means, all `CMakeLists.txt` and `*.cmake` files are read and processes. Generate means, the CMake-internal representation of the build is written to some buildsystem specific format, e.g. Makefile, ninja.build, Visual Studio projects, etc. In case you use a Multi-Config generator like "Ninja Multi-Config", Visual Studio or XCode, it might help to reduce the number of generated configurations. By default CMake generates build files for 4 configurations: `Debug`, `Release`, `RelWithDebInfo` and `MinSizeRel`. In case you only need a subset of those, you can specify the required ones using the [CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES.html) variable. From my experience (using Ninja Multi-Config) this can reduce the generation phase significantly for large projects.

### Superbuild

Use a [superbuild](https://www.kitware.com/cmake-superbuilds-git-submodules/) structure with `ExternalProject`. Here you basically have one build that orchestrates the configuration and building of several other projects. This way, the sub-builds including their configuration phases are run in parallel. Note however, that this has other issues like the targets of the other projects not being available at configure time. In my experience, superbuild are only a good choice for special use cases.

### Concurrent `execute_process()`

Someone managed write a [ray tracer using CMake](https://64.github.io/cmake-raytracer). For the parallelization he exploited that `execute_process()` runs multiple `COMMAND`s concurrently. This could help, if you have to do some heavy preprocessing that cannot be deferred to the build stage. But then again, it runs as a separate process, so if you call CMake recursively with this you don't have access to targets, variables, etc. of that subprocess.

### Do as much as possible in the Build Phase

I don't have insight into your build, but often it help to perform only the things necessary in the configuration phase. Especially for `execute_process()` calls, one should always evaluate if it could be replaced with `add_custom_command()`/`add_custom_target()`, because creating processes is relatively costly.

An example: I had once a large scale project at work where a lot of source files were generated from XML/XSLT files. Since CMake doesn't have any knowledge about the dependencies between XML/XSLT files, we had a script that figured out those dependencies by reading the files and following includes recursively. At first, this script was called using `execute_process()` at configure time in order to pass the output to the `DEPENDS` options of `add_custom_command()`. Later, I optimized this by doing the dependency evaluation at build time and generating a `.d` dependency file (Makefile syntax) that could be passed to the `DEPFILE` option of `add_custom_command()` instead. The speedup in configuration was enormous, while the build time suffered only slightly, because it in parallel.